# Webscraping Code does not work for url/Please help in modifying code

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the below working that I have inherited.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

start = datetime.now()
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data


urls = {
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        try:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
        except ValueError:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
        except AttributeError:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

print(tabulate(results, headers='keys', tablefmt="github"))
end = datetime.now()
time_taken = end - start
print('Time taken to complete: ', time_taken)


|    | date              | time   | game                             | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds | country   | league         |
|----|-------------------|--------|----------------------------------|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|----------------|
|  0 | Yesterday, 11 May | 19:15  | Southampton - Crystal Palace     | 3:1     |        1.89 |        3.8  |        4.11 | England   | Premier League |
|  1 | Yesterday, 11 May | 17:00  | Manchester Utd - Leicester       | 1:2     |        3.72 |        3.58 |        2.07 | England   | Premier League |
|  2 | 10 May 2021       | 19:00  | Fulham - Burnley                 | 0:2     |        2.24 |        3.44 |        3.38 | England   | Premier League |
|  3 | 09 May 2021       | 18:00  | Arsenal - West Brom              | 3:1     |        1.5  |        4.53 |        6.76 | England   | Premier League |
|  4 | 09 May 2021       | 15:30  | West Ham - Everton               | 0:1     |        2.15 |        3.56 |        3.48 | England   | Premier League |
```

I now need to get similar data output for https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/

When I change the url to:

```
urls = {
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Harshad/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_36.py", line 79, in <module>
    game_data = parse_data(url)
  File "C:/Users/Harshad/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_36.py", line 48, in parse_data
    league = count[2].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am completely new to scraping data from the web hence this newbie question on how I can modify this code to make it work.

Please help

Answer (score -1):

Run `len(count)` to check the number of elements in count. It might have found only 1 element. So when you try count[2].text it gives the IndexError.

Comment: Where would try `len(count)` ? I mean which part should I substitute in the code with `len(count)`

Comment: After count = main.findAll('a')